# Get maximum and minimum value from lineseries

Tags: lightningchart

i add values to lineseries like below

```
line.add({x:xVal,y:yVal});
```

Is there any method to get maximum and minimum value from this line series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`series.getXMax()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/lineseries.html#getxmax), [`series.getXMin()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/lineseries.html#getxmin), [`series.getYMax()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/lineseries.html#getymax) and [`series.getYMin()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/lineseries.html#getymin) to get the minimum and maximum values of a series.

Alternatively you can use [`series.getBoundaries()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/lineseries.html#getboundaries) to get the minimum and maximum values in a single object.

```js
const series = chart.addLineSeries()
series.add([
  {x: 0, y: 1},
  {x: 2, y: 3}
])

series.getXMin() // 0
series.getYMin() // 1
series.getXMax() // 2
series.getYMax() // 3
```

Comment: Yupe I found in this example - https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0006-pointClusters.html